# how do i fetch this data from realtime firebase database and add to a list?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch temp from this below data entries in firebase and add it to list, how to do it?

```
1234567789
   bpm: 65
   temp:21
```

My function to fetch and add to a list is this:

```
  List<int> temp=[];
  fetchdata() async{
    var url='https://reva-quarantine-project.firebaseio.com/$result';
    final response = await http.get(url);
     final extractedData = json.decode(response.body);
      
     extractedData.forEach((data){
       temp.add(data['temp']);
       
     });
  }
```

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: What is the value of `$result`? Also: when you run this code and step through it in the debugger, which specific line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: result is what i am fetching from firestore db and here it is 1234567789

Answer (score 0):

To access the Firebase Realtime Database through its REST API the URL must end with `.json`. Without that, you're actually trying to access the Firebase console.

So:

```
var url='https://reva-quarantine-project.firebaseio.com/$result.json';
```

Comment: how to add the fetched data to the list temp?